# Keeping tags clean from the start

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to provide some basic reminders regarding tags. As many of you will know from the other SE sites you participate in, tags are not on the top of the pile functionality wise in the SE sites. However if we keep it a sensible taxonomy from the start we have a good chance to make it better.

Let me start out with the obvious.

- **Look for existing tags.** Even now in beta. No, especially now in beta. Open the tags page and have a look at it before creating new ones.
- Think before you tag. [Don't create meta tags.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- Be on the look out for bad tags. We already have some the roomba will delete tonight. (Someone created [optional](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optional) ...) Edit out those abominations early and with prejudice.
- If you are unsure about it, ask about it on meta.

Let's do it right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

How can tag synonyms be created? Trinary should be a synonym of ternary...

Comment: It really should be. They can be created by enough users with the proper [privileges](https://iota.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) or mods which means in private beta community managers like Robert. Synonym count is not a problem as you can see on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: @Helmar: Thanks. Will probably take a few more days until somebody has 1250 rep here. :D

Comment: That's why I mentioned the Community Managers. Usually they gladly help out when asked nicely and presented with a reasonable argument. The one you mention sounds slam-dunky.